# Knex error: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I'm using Knex.js in a relational database. Currently trying to do a relatively simple join, no aliases involved.

```
knex('tools_users')
  .select('*').from('tools_users')
  .innerJoin('users', 'users.id', 'tools_users.user_id')
  .innerJoin('tools', 'tools.id', 'tools_users.tool_id')
  .where('users.id', userId)
  .andWhere('tools.id', toolId)
  .andWhere('tools_users.current_durability', '>', 0)
  .first()
  .decrement('tools_users.current_durability', durabilityUsed)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('tool updated');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

That `console.error(err)` is producing this error: `error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "users"`

Every solution I've found elsewhere online shows that it was an alias issue. I'm not using any aliases though. Not sure what else there is to do.
I've found knex issues on the github repo to be inconclusive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knex doesn't support joining data for update queries so you have to make two separate queries... Something like these (I didn't test the queries, so there might be typos):

```
knex('tools_users')
  .innerJoin('users', 'users.id', 'tools_users.user_id')
  .innerJoin('tools', 'tools.id', 'tools_users.tool_id')
  .where('users.id', userId)
  .andWhere('tools.id', toolId)
  .andWhere('tools_users.current_durability', '>', 0)
  .first()
  .then((tool_user) => {
    return knex('tool_user').where('id', tool_user.id)
      .decrement('current_durability', durabilityUsed);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('tool updated');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

or single query with subquery

```
knex('tools_users')
  .decrement('current_durability', durabilityUsed)
  .whereIn('id', (subQueryBuilder) => {
    subQueryBuilder
      .from('tools_users')
      .select('id')
      .innerJoin('users', 'users.id', 'tools_users.user_id')
      .innerJoin('tools', 'tools.id', 'tools_users.tool_id')
      .where('users.id', userId)
      .andWhere('tools.id', toolId)
      .andWhere('tools_users.current_durability', '>', 0)
      .limit(1);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('tool updated');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up removing the .decrement() chainable and came to the same conclusion. I can post what I came up with if anybody is ever interested.